# How to bypass cloudflare server to get some site which using it?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, cloudflare

I tried to bypass CF server to get AMF (addmefast) site using Java.

I used `HttpURLConnecting` but AMF site's response code is 200 (normally it must return 302 code) and when I try to get AMF's page, it returns unreadable code!

Here is what I tried:

```java
URL obj=new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)obj.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Host","addmefast.com");
//...continue setRequestProperty...
//...
int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code: "+responseCode);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
//...print page content on screen...
in.close();
```

I'm trying to create an auto can login to AMF.

Can anyone tell how to bypass CF to get the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you getting back for a response with CloudFlare?

It is quite possible that whatever you're doing is triggering a security feature of some sort, which only the site owner could really address.

Comment: @LonelyGuy Can you describe how you did it? I have the same problem.